# Can HttpServlet response an object which is an instance of my own class to the client with doGet() method or other method?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Can HttpServlet response an object which is an instance of my own class to the client with doGet() method or other method?

what i have in mind is to send a serialized object created in the client-side, have the server-side process it and send back a serialized object -'backend object'- to the client-side as a response.

Take in Consideration that i just started reading about servlets, this question pooped-up into my head while doing my readings as to see if i would achieve my goal with servlets or i am going the wrong path, please be nice and don't tell me to google it, cos i am already googling and reading everything i find about servlets.

Thank You In Advance :D

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, "instance object class to the client with doGet()"?

Comment: Sorry but before we can even think of asking you to Google it, we are not following your question.

Comment: Sorry, i had edited my post to clear the ambiguity.

Comment: Do you mean to ask that an backend object can be returned to the client as a response ?

Comment: @Rohan: i am not sure what you mean by backend object, googled "java backend object" nothing useful came up. what i have in mind is to send a serialized object created in the client-side, have the server-side process it and send back a serialized object to the client-side as a response.

Comment: @Shikatsu. That is descriptive enough. I think you should add that to your question. With 'backend object' I meant a server side object. To answer your question, yes you can pass an object back to the server and get a modified object back provided you serialize the object to text and deserialize it to your object on bothe sides. look into JSON http://www.json.org/

Comment: @Rohan:Thank you, i had added it to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can pass an object back to the server and get a modified object back **provided** you serialize the object to text and de-serialize it to your object on both sides. Look into [JSON](http://json.org) . It is one of the popular methods by which to achieve object exchange as you've described.

Comment: I'll accept your answer and look it up when time come up, Thank You a Lot. if anyone have something to add please do.

Comment: Feel free to comment here further if there is anything you need clarification for. There are other ways like SOAP, which is an Xml based object exchange format. It definitely depends on what technologies your client and server are using and the complexity of the objects you are trying to pass over the HTTP connection. Best.